# ggplot2 is there an easy way to wrap annotation text?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm currently using [ggplot2](http://ggplot2.org/) and the annotate function, an example from the documentation is below. I have limited width to annotate text of unknown length and need an automatic way to wrap it within some `x_start` and `x_end` values. Since I don't want to change the font size, I will also need to shift the `y` value depending on how many breaks are introduced. Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

```
# install.packages(c("ggplot2"), dependencies = TRUE)
require(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point()
p + annotate("text", x = 4, y = 25, label = "Some arbitrarily larger text")
```

Comment: Have a look at `strwrap(...)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative solution using only `base` and `ggplot2`.

Building from what you presented above

```
# First a simple wrapper function (you can expand on this for you needs)
wrapper <- function(x, ...) paste(strwrap(x, ...), collapse = "\n")
# The a label
my_label <- "Some arbitrarily larger text"
# and finally your plot with the label
p + annotate("text", x = 4, y = 25, label = wrapper(my_label, width = 5))
```

Comment: Doesn't the specific font and bold setting play a role in finding the character width for the given text in this answer?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the issue. Could you make an example how that cause a problem in your example?

Comment: The problem is that my constraint width is in pixels and not in characters. To use your solution I would need to transform from pixels width (taking into account font, bold setting etc) to characters width.

Comment: I see. Sorry, I didn't get that at first. If your plot size is constant wouldn't the width _in characters_ be equivalent to a _width in pixels_? If you plot size not constant (like `pdf()` … `dev.off()`) I can't see how you can use a constant width in pixels? Could you elaborate?

Comment: With `wrapper <- Vectorize(function(x, ...) paste(strwrap(x, ...), collapse = "\n"))` this solution also works for the case of multiple annotations eg when using `geom_text` instead of `annotate`.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the `splitTextGrob` function from `RGraphics` package can help. This will wrap the text depending on the width of the plot window.

```
library(RGraphics)
library(ggplot2)


p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point()

grob1 <-  splitTextGrob("Some arbitrarily larger text")

p + annotation_custom(grob = grob1,  xmin = 3, xmax = 4, ymin = 25, ymax = 25)
```

Comment: Doesn't the specific font and bold setting play a role in finding the character width for the given text in this answer?

Comment: Also, the output produced is left justified, is there a way to get it center justified?

Comment: The size of the text will make a difference in whether the text is wrapped or not relative to the same size plot window - although the text wont be split beyond the word level. Re the justification, i thought a `just` parameter could be passed but not had any luck ie like this `splitTextGrob("Some arbitrarily larger text", gp=gpar(fontsize=20, col="red"),just = "center")` [ the `just` doesn't work.] . Using `fontsize` might give you some of the control you want over text size - see `?gpar`

Comment: One way to center the text is by tweaking [drawDetails.splitText function](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Elu6zp4E9qAC&pg=PA257&lpg=PA257&dq=splittextgrob+just&source=bl&ots=_vZAtzKr15&sig=to4YnpeIe8R-66ZdSiU0D32DgyE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=e33eU5qeC62M7Aap4oG4DA&ved=0CEQQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=splittextgrob%20just&f=false) , although i am sure there is a more sensible way

Answer (score 5):

I use a tidyverse stringr solution similar to Eric Fail, though without the need to create a function (which, neither does Eric's, to be transparent):

```
# use str_wrap to wrap long text from annotate
p + annotate(
  "text", x = 4, y = 25,
  label = stringr::str_wrap(
    "Some arbitrarily larger text",
     width = 20
  )
)
```