# Add geom_hline legend to existing geom bar legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I want to add a legend under the existing legend that represents the dashed line, such that the dashed line could be labeled "avg tx effect" and be placed under study 3.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

#dput(df)

df=structure(list(study = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("study1", "study2", 
"study3"), class = "factor"), d = c(-0.205, 0.1075, 0.3525, -0.37, 
0.3, 0.42, -0.28, 0.09, 0.59, 0.11, -0.05, 0.25, 0, 0.25, 0.49
), Outcome = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L), Outcome2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 13L, 13L, 13L), .Label = c("1", "1", "1", 
"2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "5", "5", "5"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("study", 
"d", "Outcome", "Outcome2"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(df, aes(x=Outcome2, y=d, fill=study)) + 
   geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), aes(x=Outcome2),stat="identity",
             colour="black", # Use black outlines,
             size=.3) +      # Thinner lines
    xlab("Outcome") +
    ylab("Cohen's D Effect Size") +
    scale_fill_grey(name="Study", 
                   labels=c("study1","study2", "study3"))+
        theme_bw()+
    geom_hline(yintercept=.15,linetype=2)
```

Comment: A direct text label on the plot would be quite easy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Gregor suggested, you could use a direct label for this line by adding `annotate()` as shown below:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Outcome2, y=d, fill=study)) + 
   geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), aes(x=Outcome2),stat="identity",
             colour="black", # Use black outlines,
             size=.3) +      # Thinner lines
    xlab("Outcome") +
    ylab("Cohen's D Effect Size") +
    scale_fill_grey(name="Study", 
                   labels=c("study1","study2", "study3"))+
        theme_bw()+
    geom_hline(yintercept=.15,linetype=2) +annotate("text",x=.7,y=.17,size=3,label=c('avg tx ef'))
```

[image]

If space is an issue you can use the `wrapper` described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25106508/ggplot2-is-there-an-easy-way-to-wrap-annotation-text) to wrap the text. Just run `wrapper <- function(x, ...) paste(strwrap(x, ...), collapse = "\n")` then add `+annotate("text",x=.7,y=.18,size=3,label=wrapper('avg tx effect',10))`. Which produces:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

A general feature of `ggplot` is that to generate a legend, you need to *map* your `aes`thetics (e.g. `linetype`) to a variable in the data, instead of *setting* it to constant. In the case of `geom_hline`, this may be achieved by putting the intercept in a separate data frame. Also note `show_guide = TRUE`.

Then customize the legend using `scale_linetype_manual`. The black lines in the `fill` legend are removed using `override.aes`.

Here's a stripped down version of your code to show only the most necessary steps:

```
df2 <- data.frame(yi = 0.15)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Outcome2, y = d, fill = study)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
  geom_hline(data = df2, aes(yintercept = yi, linetype = factor(yi)), show_guide = TRUE) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "avg tx effect", values = "dashed", labels = "") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = "blank")))
```

[image]